# Determine if the difference between two dates will be shown in months, weeks or days

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I was wondering how to show the number of days, which is the difference of the start and end date. For example:

Using Carbon's diffInDays()

```
$diff = $start_date->diffInDays($end_date)
```

Now, let's say that the difference of $start_date and $end_end is 30 days. We all know that when using the Modulo operation(%) we can show that the difference between the two is 1 month since 30 is divisible by 30, it's the same as if the difference is 7 days, we can show it as 1 week.

But when the difference, for example is 35 days, 35%30 = 5, we have a remainder of 5 days. My problem is how can I show this as simple "35 days". Here's what I did so far.

```
$start_date = Carbon::parse($job->start_date);
$end_date = Carbon::parse($job->end_date)

$diff = $start_date->diffInDays($end_date);

if ($diff%30 == 0) {

  //show $result as 1 Month    

} else if ($diff%7 == 0) {

  //show $result as 1 Week  

} else {

  //show $result as $diff  

}

dd($result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are dealing with an instance of Carbon and want to display the timestamp in a human readable format, you can do something like the below:

```
$start_date = Carbon::parse($job->start_date);
$end_date = Carbon::parse($job->end_date);
$start_date->diffForHumans($end_date, true); // 1 week
```

Depending on the timestamp it will return things like: 3 seconds ago, 1 week ago, 1 month ago and so forth.

Edit:
the 2nd argument which i `true` removes the "ago" part of the returned string, so without it the returned value would be "1 week ago" instead of "1 week"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already tried this before, but it's not exactly what I wanted, For example $diff = 13 days, we can't say 13 days is equal to 2 weeks, so we to display it as is "13 days". using diffForHumans() it only returns "1 week"

Answer (score -1):

Finally got it to work, here's what I did

```
$start_date = Carbon::parse('2023-08-18');
$end_date = Carbon::parse('2023-09-15';

// Calculate the differences
$months = $start_date ->floatDiffInMonths($end_date );
$weeks = $start_date ->floatDiffInWeeks($end_date );

if (fmod($months, 1) == floatval(0)) {
   dd($months.' '.'Month/s');
} elseif (fmod($weeks, 1) == floatval(0)) {
   dd($weeks.' '.'Week/s');
} else {
   $days =  $start_date ->diffInDays($end_date );
   dd($days .' '.'Day/s');
}
```

the result will be "4 Week/s"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**